# Using Inner Classes As Type Arguments

Tags: scala, generics, inner-classes, abstract-type

I need to use an inner class or abstract type as a type argument for an outer type, such as in the heavily simplified example below:

```
trait A[T <: Ordered[T]] {
}

class B extends A[C] { //<-- Compiler error, type C not found.
  class C extends Ordered[C] {
  }
}
```

I've come to a rather thorny design problem in my library, and I don't see any satisfying way to avoid this construction.  I've tried a number of different wanys to reference the inner class from the type argument, but to no avail.

My questions are:

1. Is there any way to reference an inner class from the type argument of an outer class?
2. If not, is there a logical inconsistency that precludes this, or it simply a limitation of the compiler and language specification?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First of all, you would need to qualify `C` to be the internal class, for example with a projection:

```
class B extends A[B#C] {
  class C extends Ordered[C]
}
```

This produces an "illegal cyclic reference", so it is a limitation of the compiler

You could change the type constructor parameter in `A` to a type member:

```
trait A {
  type T <: Ordered[T]
}

class B extends A {
  class T extends Ordered[T] {
    def compare(that: T): Int = ???
  }
}
```

Comment: Actually, even if your first example did compile, it's not quite what I need.  I would need this.C, not A#C, because C implemented Ordered[this.C] not Ordered[B#C].  It seems that being able to use inner classes and abstract types as type arguments would be useful (using type parameters as arguments is quite common, in fact).  Again, I'm not sure if allowing this would create some logical inconsistency in the type system, or its simply a lexical limitation of the language.

Comment: This is correct. You can verify that by introducing `trait BLike { class T ... }; class B extends BLike with A[BLike#T]`, it does not compile. A future version Scala ("Dotty") will likely fuse the concepts of type constructor parameters and type members.

Comment: That will be an interesting fusion, I think.